# ansible-galaxy - git clone and SSH "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: linux, git, ssh, ansible, gitlab

We face problems with series of clones with git ssh when they are executed in a short time.

For example, with ansible-galaxy, we need to download about 30 roles from gitlab.
Currently, it crashes between 18 to 20 clones
The error:

**client side**

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

**Server side**

```sh
Did not receive identification string from x.x.x.x.x
```

To reproduce:

```sh
REPO=git@<gitlab>:<repo>.git
for i in {1..30}; do git clone $REPO clone$i; done
```

Or direcly in ssh

```
SERVER=<one server>
for i in {1..25}; do ssh $SERVER echo "try$i"; done
```

SSH settings on gitlab serveur  ( /etc/ssh/sshd_config )

```sh
MaxSessions 100
MaxStartups 100:30:100
```

To your knowledge, are there modifications that can be made to SSHD, limits or sysctl, to allow more connection please ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunately, this question is not related to programming and [off-topic](/help/on-topic) on this site. It is probably better suitted for https://superuser.com

Comment: My advice is to configure ssh connection sharing (multiplexing) either at [ssh](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) or at [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-ssh-args)

Comment: Have you tried other alternatives mentioned here in this post https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-connection-reset-by-peer-ssh-error

Comment: Hi, after losing 3 days, I just found it. we have a PaloAlto firewall in front of the gitlab server, it is able to do application filtering (OSI level 7).
The flow was open in tcp/22, but the firewall recognizes the SSH protocol.
The firewall considers that the 30 SSH requests in 20s from the same client are not normal and cuts the flow, which gives "“Connection reset by peer”" on the client side.
The solution is therefore to make "Application Override" in the PaloAlto firewall, so that it does not analyze the SSH flow structure and make a simple level 4 opening in tcp.